# Adding Custom Metric to CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I need to add an alarm the triggers a rollback in CloudFormation. I've settled on adding a custom metric that can be assigned manually. I'm looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html). This looks like it would work but I need it to be added to the template. Is this possible? The way I'm thinking initially the value would be 0 failures like below

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Failures --namespace MyNamespace --value 0
```

when I want to trigger a rollback I would set it to 1

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Failures --namespace MyNamespace --value 1
```

But I need this to be in the template so that I can have access to the correct/dynamic value of the `namespace` when defining the alarm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cloudformation simple template to add metrics

> resource "AWS::Logs::MetricFilter" specifies a metric filter that
> describes how CloudWatch Logs extracts information from logs and
> transforms it into Amazon CloudWatch metrics. If you have multiple
> metric filters that are associated with a log group, all the filters
> are applied to the log streams in that group.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-metricfilter.html

sample

```
404MetricFilter: 
  Type: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
  Properties: 
    LogGroupName: 
      Ref: "myLogGroup"
    FilterPattern: "[ip, identity, user_id, timestamp, request, status_code = 404, size]"
    MetricTransformations: 
      - 
        MetricValue: "1"
        MetricNamespace: "WebServer/404s"
        MetricName: "404Count"
```

Answer (score 1):

unless you want to do this via a [cloudformation custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html)

you can use this as well [Running bash commands in AWS CloudFormation templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/running-bash-commands-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/)

With the above you can run your command like

```yaml
Resources:
  CommandRunner:
    Type: AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner
    Properties:
      Command: 'aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Failures --namespace MyNamespace --value 1'
```

Comment: Doesn't look like command runner is supported for serverless

Comment: I read the question for cloudformation, and after installing this <AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner>, I am able to run bash commands directly in the template. I assume most of the clauses works similarly between both SAM and CFN Templates.